# In this piano notation, which hand plays which notes?

Tags: piano, notation

For the final 3 chords/notes, what hand plays what?

(The piece is Lilium Elfen Lied OP, Transcribed by TehIshter.)

[image: lilium]

Comment: Are there pedal markings in the piece?

Comment: there are no pedal markings in this entire piece, so the player has to put them whenever they see it suited

Comment: See whether TheIshter has a video of himself playing this piece, then look at his hands as he plays that passage if possible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the transcriber intends all pitches in the bass clef to be played with the left hand and all pitches in the treble clef to be played by the right hand.

The slurred eighth-note passage that begins on the low F♯ is all one line (as shown with the dotted line in the score), but the G♯, B, and A should be played with the right hand. You'll have the release the half-note chord in the right hand early, but you can use pedal to keep that chord sustained.

And make sure you practice a smooth trade-off between the hands!

Comment: I might use the left to take that G#, though.

Answer (score 1):

Right hand plays top clef, left hand plays bottom.   The dotted line indicates the musical phrase moving from one hand to the other.  Some pedalling certainly seems appropriate!

Comment: I might take the B in beat 3 with the right hand myself, since I would certainly take the following A with the right hand. Also, I would probably pedal the entire half-note chord, so the low F would carry through.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the left hand to play G#-B (3 crotchets in). The following A would probably have to be played (despite the notation) with your right hand (unless you have extremely large hands) as you are required to play an F# and D as well. I believe it is notated in such a way for fluency of phrasing.